# Bad Character code (256)/ \select@language{greek}

Tags: errors, listings, greek

I was trying to install `minted` package in `TeXLive`. I installed it and then run `sudo tlmgr update --all`. It was running slow so I stopped it using `Ctrl+Z` in an `ubuntu` terminal and then I run `sudo tlmgr update --list`. After that I installed `texlive-latex-extra` and `python-pygments`. Later on I run `sudo tlmgr update --all` again and let it finish.

After that I am trying to run a simple code using `listings` and greek but I get an error

> Bad Character code (256)

A MWE that illustrated the problem is the following

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
% %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{pifont}
% % 
\newcommand{\sw}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\sq}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}
\newcommand{\gre}[1]{\greektext#1\latintext}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\lstdefinestyle{JavaStyle}{
        backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,
%   rulecolor=,
    language=Java,      % choose the language of the code
        basicstyle=\scriptsize,     % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
        upquote=true,
        aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
        columns=fixed,
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=false,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=single,
        numbers=left,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
        %commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.026,0.112,0.095},
        commentstyle=\itshape\color{green!40!black},
        stringstyle=\itshape\color{red!90!black},
        numberstyle=\itshape\color{yellow!50!black}
}

\lstdefinestyle{CppStyle}{
        backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,
%   rulecolor=,
    language=C++,       % choose the language of the code
        basicstyle=\scriptsize,     % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
        upquote=true,
        aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
        columns=fixed,
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=false,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=single,
        numbers=left,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
        %commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.026,0.112,0.095},
        commentstyle=\itshape\color{green!40!black},
        stringstyle=\itshape\color{red!90!black},
        numberstyle=\itshape\color{yellow!50!black}
}
\begin{document}
 This is a dummy text. kjhbki
\end{document}
```

The `.aux` file says

```
\relax 
\select@language{greek}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{greek}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{greek}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{greek}}
```

while the `.log` file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/HEjkqnx7)

Any idea why is this happening and how to fix this? Note that if I remove the `listings` preamble, delete all produced files and build the document, everything works fine.

Comment: You should use UTF-8 as the encoding for your files, not iso-8859-7

Comment: @egreg:Even if I use `utf8` the result is the same. I get the same error.

Comment: I have added to my answer a proposed bug fix for `greek.ldf` and also a better temporary fix.

Comment: The `babel-greek` suite has been updated, but unfortunately the bug still remains.

Comment: That's bad... I have already sent a bug report...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ## UPDATE
>
> The problem has been fixed with `babel-greek` version 1.9e, released on 2015/11/27

## Original answer

Here's a temporary fix, that should work if Greek is the last language loaded; it just restores the value of `\@tempcnta` to what it would be if `listings` is not loaded. However, this is a bug in `babel-greek`: no package should rely on any particular value of `\@tempcnta`; my impression is that some code has been added that is useless.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\originalTeX\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\@tempcnta\number253\expandafter\relax\originalTeX}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

The bad code is in line 376 of `greek.ldf` that says

```
376       \babel@savevariable{\lccode\@tempcnta}\lccode\@tempcnta=\@tempcnta
```

while it should be

```
376       \expandafter\babel@savevariable\expandafter{\expandafter\lccode\the\@tempcnta}\lccode\@tempcnta=\@tempcnta
```

so the correct instructions

```
\babel@savevariable{\lccode128}
\babel@savevariable{\lccode129}
...
\babel@savevariable{\lccode252}
```

are executed instead of doing several times the useless (and wrong)

```
\babel@savevariable{\lccode\@tempcnta}
```

Thus a better temporary fix would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
% Avoid the spurious error
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\originalTeX\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\@tempcnta\number253\expandafter\relax\originalTeX}%
}
% apply the fix
\addto\extrasgreek{%
  \@tempcnta=128
  \@whilenum\@tempcnta<253\do{%
    \expandafter\babel@savevariable\expandafter{\expandafter\lccode\the\@tempcnta}%
    \lccode\@tempcnta=\@tempcnta
    \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
a
b
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

(Too long for a comment). It is a babel bug. It relies on a temporary counter and fails when listings sets it to `256`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\@tempcnta=256
\selectlanguage{greek}

\end{document}
```

Sent a bug report to the babel maintainer or the `babel-greek` maintainer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your shocking answer! First of all, this happened because I've updated my packages? Secondly, is `\makeatletter \@tempcnta=256 \selectlanguage{greek}` suppossed to fix this? I've added this right after `begin{document}` but I get the exact same error... Last but not least, how to give a bug report? Is there a certain way or I'll just to communicate with the creator via email?

Comment: No the example doesn't fix it, it shows that the error can be triggered easily without listings. Try `\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\@tempcnta=10}
\makeatother` after `\usepackage{listings}. And write a message here http://www.tex-tipografia.com/contact.html

Comment: Yes, when `\originalTeX` is executed, a number of `\lccode\@tempcnta=<number>` instructions are performed without any initialization to `\@tempcnta`; I'm not sure where they come from and what they're for.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : Yes you are right. It fixes the issue. I'll contact the developers! Thank you very much!