# Why do I get these errors?

Tags: errors, pdftex, chapters, languages

A part of the code that I have written is the following:

```
   \documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english,greek]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathdots} 

\usepackage{cite} 

\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks]{titlesec}  

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newtheorem{mylemma}{Λήμμα}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Θεώρημα}[chapter] 
\newtheorem*{myproofidea*}{Ιδέα της απόδειξης}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Ορισμός}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{example}{Παράδειγμα}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{corollary}{Πόρισμα}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{remark}{Παρατήρηση}[chapter]

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
  {4ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}}
  [\vspace{2ex}\titlerule] 

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{} 

\DeclareMathOperator{\Char}{char} 

\begin{document} 

\title{  }

\author{  } 

\date{ }

\maketitle 

\clearpage 

\tableofcontents 

\clearpage 

\chapter{ Εισαγωγή } 

\chapter{Θεωρία 1} 

\section{Ενότητα} 

\chapter{Θεωρία 2} 

\chapter{Πρόβλημα του \foreignlanguage{english}{Grothendieck}} 



\end{document}
```

When I compile it I get the following errors:

[image]

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I get lots of warnings with that code because you are using incompatible things. But I do not get any errors. My best guess would be that your `.tex` file is not UTF8 encoded.

Comment: But what's `\originalTeX`? ***Does the exact code you've posted give those errors when pasted into a new `.tex` file?***

Comment: @OP Can you minimise the code? It would be good to find the absolute minimum necessary to produce the error. Take out any line which you can remove while still producing the error.

Comment: Received several alerts and an error from package siunitx: `support package expl3 too old.` After updating Miktex everything is ok, compiled without errors/alerts.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the given example but imho it could be triggered by this bug http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200295/2388.

Comment: I agree with @UlrikeFischer that it's an instance of the described bug: if I add `\usepackage{listings}` to your example I get a similar error message. I'll try later to contact Günter Milde.

Comment: Having deleted some commands I could also compiled the code without errors. Now I added again some commands and I get some errors... I edited the code at my original question...

Comment: @egreg: I was curious and so tracked it down: In this case the error is triggered by the `\contentsline` from the section command. The KOMA classes use `\@tempcnta` in `\bprot@dottedtocline`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So there are *two* bugs, if KOMA uses `\@tempcnta` without reinitializing it.

Comment: @egreg: I don't think that there is a bug in KOMA. It simply sets  `\@tempcnta` to 20008 and then directly uses it. This is how one should use scratch counter. So why should it reset it (and to what?).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OK, that's fine, then. Let's hope Günter fixes the bug.

Comment: I just got this message from Günter Mielde: “Thank you for the report, the patch and the reminder. I applied the fix and uploaded a new version (1.9e) to CTAN.”

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't get any error with the original code, though, while Kurt did. At least, that's certainly how it seemed.... Mine did have `\section` and did create a ToC.

Comment: The problem has been fixed with `babel-greek` version 1.9e, released on 2015/11/27